# UK business visa - Marital status is married but spouse does not have passport

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

I am applying for UK Business Visa. I am married and I have to travel alone. While applying for Visa I need to fill the marital status, I am choosing married but there it is asking for passport no. of my wife. 
My wife doesn't have passport. What to fill in that field as it is a mandatory field.

Answer (score 3):

You can write "not applicable" or "none."

Comment: Can you please share me any official document where it is mentioned to write 'Not applicable or None'.

Comment: @Sumit I cannot.  But what else would you put?  Also, there is no UK visa called a "business visa."  What kind of visa are you actually applying for?  Is it a *Standard Visitor visa?*  What web site are you using to apply?

Comment: I am using www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk.

Comment: Visa type - Visit - business - 6 months.